# Heed help regarding scroller slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any jQuery expert helps me to get out of this. I'm new to jQuery.

I got one jquery slider and it has five sections after scroll it takes us to the next section but when we go to the last section that is the fifth section scroll down gets disabled. But there is some content so the problem is after the fifth section it should display that content but it's not showing 
below is my HTML and jquery code

I tried a lot but could not get a proper solution. 
I think there is a minor error.

```js
// variables
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
var $nav = $('nav');



// toggle menu 
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});



// fullpage customization
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#B8AE9C', '#348899', '#F2AE72', '#5C832F', '#B8B89F'],
  sectionSelector: '.vertical-scrolling',
  slideSelector: '.horizontal-scrolling',
  navigation: true,
  slidesNavigation: true,
  controlArrows: false,
  anchors: ['firstSection', 'secondSection', 'thirdSection', 'fourthSection', 'fifthSection'],
  menu: '#menu',

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
    $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
    if (index == 5) {
        $('#fp-nav').hide();
      }
  },

  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    if(index == 5) {
      $('#fp-nav').show();
    }
  },

  afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
    if(anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up');
      $header_top.css('background', 'transparent');
      $nav.css('background', 'transparent');
      $(this).css('background', '#374140');
      $(this).find('h2').css('color', 'white');
      $(this).find('h3').css('color', 'white');
      $(this).find('p').css(
        {
          'color': '#DC3522',
          'opacity': 1,
          'transform': 'translateY(0)'
        }
      );
    }
  },

  onSlideLeave: function( anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
    if(anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'up');
      $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
      $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
    }
  } 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fullpage.js demo</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <header>
  <div class="header-top clearfix">
    <h1 class="l-left"><a href="#firstSection">Your Logo</a></h1>
    <a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav class="hide">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li data-menuanchor="firstSection">
        <a href="#firstSection" title="First Section">First Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="secondSection">
        <a href="#secondSection" title="Second Section">Second Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="thirdSection">
        <a href="#thirdSection" title="Second Section">Third Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fourthSection">
        <a href="#fourthSection" title="Fourth Section">Fourth Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection">
        <a href="#fifthSection" title="First Slide">First Slide</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection/1">
        <a href="#fifthSection/1" title="Second Slide">Second Slide</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="fullpage">
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the first section</h3>
    <div class="scroll-icon">
      <p>Jump into the last slide</p>
      <a href="#fifthSection/1" class="icon-up-open-big"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the second section</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the third section</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2> 
    <h3>This is the fourth section</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <div class="horizontal-scrolling">
      <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
      <h3>This is the fifth section and it contains the first slide (actually section == first slide)</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-scrolling"> 
     <h2>fullPage.js</h2> -->
     <h3>This is the second slide</h3>  
      <p class="end">Thank you!</p> 
</div>
  </section>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<span class="abc" style="width:100%;height:30%">
additonal content </span>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have the code that says if index == 5 then $('#fp-nav').hide(); so do not hide when index is 5.

Comment: $('#fp-nav').hide() this will hide only and it doesnot matter if its get hide

Comment: What might help you get better answers is stripping down your code to the bare minimum. Maybe start with removing your css and any unnecessary markup. So you just end up with some sections and slides. It'll make it easier for people to scan your code.